# Totalizar somatória com linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

Não tenho ideia de como fazer para obter o **Valor Total = 755.00** desse select com **Linq** ?

```
| ID |Qtde  | Valor  | Total |
|  1 |  10  | 23.00  | 230.00|
|  1 |  15  | 10.00  | 150.00|
|  1 |  15  | 25.00  | 375.00| 
Total:                 755.00
```

Imagino algo assim:

```
var _total = from cta in ListConta()
         .Where(c => c.ContaID == pContaID)
         select new ContaView
         {
             ContaID = cta.ContaID ,
             Qtde = cta.Qtde,
             ValorTotal = cta.Pedido.ItensPedido.Sum(c => c.Valor)
         };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sua pergunta não tem muitos detalhes, mas se você esta querendo mostra 
uma grade como você mostrou no inicio da pergunta ficaria assim;

```
var _total = from cta in ListConta()
         .Where(c => c.ContaID == pContaID)
         select new ContaView
         {
             ContaID = cta.ContaID ,
             Qtde = cta.Qtde,
             Valor = cta.Pedido.ItensPedido.Valor,
             ValorTotal = cta.Pedido.ItensPedido.Valor * cta.Qtde,
         };
```

Se você precisar mostra o tatal bruto, teria que monta isso com uma 
UI, para isso basta criar uma varivavel com o valor.

```
var TotalBruto = _total.Sum(t => t.ValorTotal);
```

Comment: perfeito! Obrigado!